# Number of substrings with unique letters

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a string, now want to count the minimum number of substrings such that the letters in the substring should occur only once.

**Example:**

```
Input : cycle
Output : 2
```

**explanation:**

```
Possible substrings are : ('cy', 'cle') or ('c', 'ycle')
```

**Example:**

```
Input : aaaa
Output : 4
```

**explanation:**

```
Possible substrings are : ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a')
```

I am able to get all possible substrings but I am not able to understand how to achieve the solution for this task:

```
static int distinctSubString(String S) {
    int count = 0;
    int n = S.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n; j++) {
            String s = S.substring(i, j);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I'd construct the substrings by adding characters one by one until you reach one that already is present in your current substring, at which point I'd start a new substring and increment a count

Comment: I would suggest when counting the number of possible substrings, count number of unique letters in that particular substring and if it is equal to the length of the substring, it's ok. and if it is ok for every substring for that particular n, you can add those substrings to output

Comment: @Aaron, if I follow that way, I will be able to get only `('cy', 'cle')` right. I will not get `('c', 'ycle')`

Comment: You're right, but I'm not convinced yet that this is problematic if all you need is to return the minimal amount of substrings. If you need to display all the possible substrings of minimal length you might want to make that clearer in your question

Comment: So substrings must cover all the string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should note that this can be done greedily. Whenever you meet a character it can either be added to the previous partition or can start a new one. If both are possible, then you can always add to the previous partition and not change anything else, so the answer would not get worse from it. Therefore, the solution is to run across characters and whenever you and add one to the partition when you can do it. This solution is asymptotically optimal. Note that if your characters fall into a specific range using an array instead of HashSet can significantly boost performance.

```java
static int distinctSubString(String S) {
    int count = (S.isEmpty()) ? 0 : 1;
    S = S.toLowerCase();
    HashSet<Character> letters = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
        if (letters.contains(S.charAt(i))) {
            letters.clear();
            count++;
        }
        letters.add(S.charAt(i));
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but you have a lot of compile issues in your code

Comment: Forgot that java does not have square brackets syntax for strings, fixed the code. Also, importing java.util.HashSet is required to compile this;

Comment: I added (what I think is the fix) to your answer I hope you don't mind, +1 nice answer btw

Comment: What I added should fix that

Comment: @dreamcrash I had missed your init to 1 which fixed the off-by-one. I'm not sure it makes sense if testing against the empty string (your fix gives 1 substring of the empty string, mine gives 0)

Comment: @Aaron I added something to cover that

Answer (score 0):

```
static int f(String s){
    int ans=1;
    Map<Character,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
         if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i))){
                  map.clear();
                  map.put(s.charAt(i) , 1);
                  ans++;
         }
         else{
                 map.put(s.charAt(i) , 1);
         }
     }
     return ans;
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).